# Django: AutoSlug error "slug is defined before trying to ensure uniqueness"

Tags: python, django, slug

I have a model with a `django-autoslug` field:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()

    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='headline', max_length=128, allow_unicode=True, always_update=True)
```

Everything works nice in a dev environment (OS X + Postgres). However, on the deployed instance (Ubuntu + Postgres) an error occurs when trying to create an object using django admin. It occurs only when a headline has Cyrillic in it:

```
AssertionError: slug is defined before trying to ensure uniqueness
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`django-autoslug` uses `Unidecode`, but `django-autoslug` doesn't install it as a dependency. It's used to slugify unicode text. It was already installed to virtual environment on my dev machine by occasion, but server's environment was missing it. Just install it:

`pip3 install Unidecode==0.4.19`